# How to prevent USC from opening a terminal when updating the cache?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

Is there any way to change/customize, so that when you type (in terminal) `sudo apt-get update`, all the information (including download and install) is returned in the terminal instead of in a separate window?

What I'm looking for is the normal way, that (at least before and in other Linux distribution) shows what needs to be updated in plain text in the terminal and with a simple `Y/N` prompt.

Comment: Do you mean that `sudo apt-get update` displays results in a separate GUI window?

Comment: indeed... and I dont like it :P

Comment: Strange. Can you take a screenshot of this "other" window where all the information is returned to?

Comment: http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1415/ioe6.png   however theres no updates available at this time, so its returning all the information using the software updater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the `update-manager` to not automatically open when new updates are available. It typically doesn't just display a window though. It is designed to open as a minimized application, so you should only see it in the running apps list. You can simply close and ignore it, if you wish, and use `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install any packages that need upgrading, after running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: ok, and how do I configure the update-manager so that it does not auto open? I mean I still find it useful for something to remind me if there is any updates, but I dont want to get anything more then i simple notification

Comment: It seems there is no way to have it never auto-open now. But you can set the value to be once a year or month or so, to avoid it popping up when there aren't security updates. You can run `gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier regular-auto-launch-interval 365` to set it to be once every year, for example.